# Actualizar una variable PHP tipo array mediante JQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tengo un plugin en wordpress que ejecuta unos contadores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es si es posible actualizar esa variable con JQuery mediante algún evento por ejemplo al dar click en el ícono del corazón.
No pretendo que me hagan el trabajo, solamente que me digan si es posible y más o menos un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo, no soy experto en PHP y menos en JQuery.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Archivo PHP:

```
if(isset($count_options['font-color']) && $count_options['font-color'] != ''){
    $dynamic_css[] = "color: {$count_options['font-color']};";
}

if(isset($count_options['animation']['enable'])){
    $data_animation = "data-enable='on'";
}else{
    $data_animation = "data-enable='off'";
}

if(isset($count_options['animation']['enable'])){
    if(isset( $count_options['animation']['delay'] ) && $count_options['animation']['delay'] !='' ){
        $data_delay = "data-delay='{$count_options['animation']['delay']}'";
    }else{
        $data_delay = '';
    }

    if(isset( $count_options['animation']['duration'] ) && $count_options['animation']['duration'] !='' ){
        $data_duration = "data-duration='{$count_options['animation']['duration']}'";
    }else{
        $data_duration = '';
    }
}else{
    $data_delay = '';
    $data_duration ='';
}
if ($counter == 2) {
    $count_options['content'] = $count_prayer * 3;      
}   
?>
<div class="ec-count-content"><span class="ec-count-number" <?php echo $data_animation; echo $data_delay; echo $data_duration; ?> ><?php echo esc_attr($count_options['content']); ?></span><?php if($template == 'template12'){ ?><span class='ec-count-sign'>+</span><?php } ?></div>
<?php
if(isset($count_options['font-family']) && $count_options['font-family'] !=''){
    if(!in_array( $count_options['font-family'], $google_fonts_used_array) ){
        array_push($google_fonts_used_array, preg_replace('/\s/', '+', $count_options['font-family']) );
    }
    $dynamic_css[] = "font-family: {$count_options['font-family']};";
}

if(!empty($dynamic_css)){
    $dynamic_css = implode(' ', $dynamic_css);
}else{
    $dynamic_css ='';
}

ob_start();
?>
.ec-<?php echo $template; ?> .ec-counter-item-<?php echo $counter; ?> .ec-count-content .ec-count-number { <?php echo esc_attr($dynamic_css); ?> }

<?php
$ec_dynamic_css_at_end[] = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

}

Comment: seria bueno que pusieras como estas manejando este esquema actualmente es decir la estructura de tu array, es decir es solo contador o tambien guarda id de cada persona que da click o algun dato adicional..!!

Comment: Lo podridas hacer con [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp).

Comment: Hola Fran, fíjate que el array sólo maneja información de los contadores nada más, por ejemplo el título, el valor y estilo creo, ninguna otra información adicional. Te dejo el archivo PHP que se encarga de mostra el contador en el frontend:

Comment: Directamente no, JQuery trabaja del lado del cliente y PHP del lado del servidor. Tendrias que usar una llamada ajax al servidor y alli modificar la variable pero esta debe estar almacenada de forma persistente.

Comment: @JDev a que te refieres con persistente, por ejemplo que esté en una base de datos??? En el escenario actual es un variable array, no es posible en este caso???

Comment: Tambien vale una variable de session. Cualquier cosa que puedas recuperar en 2 scrips distintos.

Comment: Gracias a todos por sus aportes, ahora tengo una idea más clara de lo que tengo que hacer.

Answer (score 1):

Al hacer click en el boton, en vias la informacion que quiras con ajax:
Ejemplo:

```
$('#idDeMiBoton').click(function(){
    var data = {nombre: nombre, tel: tel, email: email, text: texto};//datos que capturas del html si lo necesitas
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ruta hasta tu fichero php", 
                data: data,
                success: function (response) {
                   //esta funcion se ejecuta cuando la consulta devuel status: 200 "Correcto"
                }
            })
            ; 

});
```

luego en tu codigo php obtienes los datos de la peticion:

```
$request->get('nombre');
$request->get('tel');
```